# Convertir char a char*

Tags: array, c, string

me encuentro leyendo un archivo de entrada del siguiente estilo:

```
perro gato elefante
```

De cada palabra, necesito generar las siguientes cadenas de caracteres (un ejemplo con la palabra perro):

```
p
pe
per
perr
perro
 e
 er
 err
 erro
  r
  rr
  rro
   r
   ro
    o
```

Cabe destacar, que necesito comparar cada subpalabra generada, con una lista de palabras del siguiente estilo (palabras solo de ejemplo). Por esto necesito utilizar las funciones strcat y strcpy (teniendo en cuenta que existe la opción de simplemente imprimir los caracteres que desee):

```
char* lista = {el, la, uno, dos, porque}
```

En primera instancia, para almacenar una palabra, ocupo el siguiente char:

```
char *token;
```

El problema es que para lograr acceder a cada letra de palabra y concatenar las letras como mostré en el ejemplo, debo utilizar la función strcat y strcpy, funciones que (por lo que tengo entendido), reciben como entrada char*. Necesito saber como pasar un char a char*. He intentado usar el símbolo de referencia (&), sin obtener resultados:

```
void combinacion(char *palabra, char *lista[]){
    int tamPalabra = strlen(palabra);
    char *subpalabra, *l;
    char letra;
    for(int i = 0; i < tamPalabra-1; i++){
        letra = palabra[0];
        printf("char es: %c \n",letra);
        l = &letra;
        printf("char* es: %s \n",l);
        strcpy(subpalabra,l);
        printf("subpalabra es: %s\n",subpalabra);
        for(int j = i+1; i < tamPalabra-1; j++){
            /*
            subpalabra = strcat(subpalabra,letra);
            printf("%s\n",subpalabra);
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Esta conversión de char a char* me permitiría utilizar las funciones strcpy y strcat. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si `c` es una variable de tipo char, entonces `&c` es su dirección de memoria, lo que por definición es un `char*`. Por desgracia no es tan sencillo. Las funciones que mencionas no solo necesitan recibir un puntero a char, necesitan recibir un **puntero a cadena**, que es un puntero que apunta a un lugar de la memoria donde hay un char, y después de él otro, y otro... hasta que en una dirección encuentre un byte de valor 0 (ascii nulo). Esas funciones esperan ese ascii nulo para saber donde termina la cadena. Así que no basta con convertir un char en char*, hay que añadir correctamente los 0.

Comment: Un caracter aislado no es una cadena. Como mínimo necesitarás dos posiciones de memoria, una que contenga el carácter en cuestión _y la siguiente_ para contener un 0 que indique que ya no hay más caracteres en la cadena. Así que tendrías que tener algo del estilo de `char letra_str[2]` y hacer `letra_str[0] = letra; letra_str[1] = 0`. Ahora sí, ya podrás usar `letra_str` como segundo parámetro de las funciones  `strcpy()` y `strcat()`. Todo esto es terriblemente feo e ineficiente. ¿Te obligan a usar esas funciones? La respuesta de PaperBirdMaster es la forma correcta de hacerlo...

Comment: No me obligan a utilizarlo, pero no encuentro otra manera de solucionar el problema. Cada subpalabra que genera la palabra (ej: perro), necesito compararla con cada palabra de char *lista (ver si son iguales. ej: p !=el; p != la; p != uno). Para esto creo que no me sirve imprimir las subpalabras

Comment: Utilizar strcpy y strcat es algo que a mi se me ocurrió para solucionar el problema, pero si existe alguna otra manera de lograr el objetivo, puedo integrarlo al código fuente sin problemas

Answer (score 3):

Usar `strcat` y `strcpy` es innecesario a la par que ineficiente. Todos los datos están en la cadena sólo debes cambiar desde dónde y hasta dónde pintar la cadena añadiendo espacios antes de ello:

```
void f(char *token)
{
    for (int indice = 0, fin = strlen(token); indice != fin; ++indice)
    {
        for (int longitud = 1, total = strlen(token + indice); longitud <= total; ++longitud)
        {
            for (int espacios = 0; espacios != indice; ++espacios)
                printf(" ");

            printf("%.*s\n", longitud, token + indice);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Si necesitas hacer esto sobre varias palabras en una frase, basta con usar [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

```
int main()
{
    char palabras[] = "perro gato elefante";

    for (char *token = strtok(palabras, " "); token; token = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        f(token);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHBToQwFEXX9CueGJMy4ETXDH7BxJ0rdVFLYRrrKynFjeHb8ZVOh9GEpOVy3@H2Vt73Ui7LrUZpplbBYfSttvvTE7uWnMY@aOzb6hY6Lk/Cwc7bT4UF@2FZZx1wjR40tloqaOChgk4jbWjYKOTRWyfDTRM@11CWUShYRpiNYyz22k8tAR4r8NYL848F5ZlF0Iv70ERvACeR0Ct7g6txEFLbMcSstzfKFIlhOqlhOssGKsB3PIe8qBm7Eu72u/EN8@oSIYT9m47sMwtPmiE/qTNjIcuX0MjXDtdOB2HEhxPj6zuFywflnIVeeAvKqE6gV3n4/3qSqzuI1dCWp/kK1qwxzHnZXM8vx2N0pN7T/YSgLHPKTw6pHDYvyy8)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Sin embargo necesito tener almacenada cada subpalabra en alguna variable, es decir, en cada iteración que subpalabra tenga el valor de cada línea del ejemplo. Necesito comparar esta subpalabra con otras palabras, antes de generar el ejemplo mencionado, pido disculpas por no mencionarlo previamente.

Comment: Si necesitas hacer la misma operación sobre varias palabras de una frase, divide la frase en palabras con [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).